# Meaning of Continuous Charge in the Inductively Shunted Cooper Pair Box

Tags: experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing, circuit-qed

In the Cooper Pair box, the conjugate momentum $\hat{n}$ of the reduced superconducting phase variable $\hat{\varphi}$ takes only discrete, integer values due to the $2\pi$ periodicity of the phase. As this conjugate momentum is the relative charge number on the island, this corresponds to the discrete charge on the island.

[image]

In the inductively shunted CPB, the inductance destroys the periodicity of the potential in $\varphi$, we have a $\frac{1}{2}E_L \varphi^2$ term additional to the usual $\cos{(\varphi)}$ term of the Josephson Junction.

Now Girvin (http://www.capri-school.eu/lectureres/master_cqed_les_houches.pdf, after 4.41) or Koch et al. (PRL **103**, 217004 (2009)) write that this leads to the charge variable becoming continuous as opposed to integer-valued like in the CPB.

Formally, this makes sense to me: As we do not have periodic boundary conditions for $\varphi$ anymore, we will not have discreteness of the conjugate momentum, i.e. the charge anymore.

**I wonder, however, how to interpret this physically:** After all, the transferred charge must still be quantized in the form of Cooper pairs. So what is meant by the continuity of the charge here?

Comment: Hi there, nice question but this might be too "physical" for QC.SE, you might have more luck with it over on Physics.SE.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I will post it on Physics.SE if I won't get a good answer here then! The tags I used for my question are more specific to it than those I could find on Physics.SE though.

Comment: I asked this question on the physics.SE now and I understand that following the guidelines this question should be closed. I cannot do this myself as I have less than 50 reputation apparently.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP wishes to close the question after moving the question to Physics SE.

Comment: [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/682205/6004) is the physics.SE post of this question.